# Cannot call value of non-function type '[PasswordCoreData]'

Tags: swift, xcode

Having two problems in my code.
First is `let mainframe = coreDataPasswords {`. I get Cannot call value of non-function type '[PasswordCoreData]'.

Second one is at the bottom `PasswordVC.selectedPassword = selectedholder`

One is supposed to place the array of coredata into mainframe, and the other is supposed to segue to the clicked password.

```
class Home: UITableViewController {

    var mainframe : [PasswordCoreData] = []
    var selectedPassword : PasswordCoreData?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        getPasswords()
    }

    func getPasswords() {
        if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {

            if let coreDataPasswords = try? context.fetch(PasswordCoreData.fetchRequest()) as? [PasswordCoreData] {
                let mainframe = coreDataPasswords {

                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }


    func createHolder() -> [Holder] {

        let rogers = Holder()
        rogers.item = "Rogers"
        rogers.username = "username"
        rogers.password = "password"

        let bell = Holder()
        bell.item = "Bell"
        bell.username = "username@cibc.com"
        bell.password = "password123"

        return [rogers, bell]
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mainframe.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = mainframe[indexPath.row].item

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "seguePassword", sender: mainframe[indexPath.row].item)
    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let addVC = segue.destination as? addNewPassword {
            addVC.homeVC = self
        }

        if let passwordVC = segue.destination as? Password {

            if let selectedholder = sender as? Password {
                passwordVC.selectedPassword = selectedholder
                passwordVC.homeVC = self
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If any other files are required, please let me know. I'm new to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You don't need `let` and `{`

```
if let coreDataPasswords = try? context.fetch(PasswordCoreData.fetchRequest()) as? [PasswordCoreData] {
   mainframe = coreDataPasswords   
   tableView.reloadData() 
}
```

2- Make sure what type of sender

```
if let passwordVC = segue.destination as? Password { 
  if let selectedholder = sender as? Password { ??<< should be  type of sent data
```

as it's not logical that the destination vc is same cast as the sended object

Comment: thanks for explainging the issue. It helped me learn what the sender actually did as the online tutorials just expected people to know